# Stored Procedure stops responding in SSIS

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis

I'm migrating a currently functional SSIS package onto another server which is similar to current one on which it runs on.

However the stored procedures I use to select distinct rows from source table and insert them into destination table stops responding when I try to run the package in the new server.

the `sp_who2` results show CPUTime and diskIO increasing (meaning query is not blocked) and `select count(*)` doesn't work (keeps on running) so I use `sp_spaceused` procedure to see number of rows which sometimes exceed the rows in the source table!

Stopping the package doesn't stop the query and I have to ask DBA to manually kill the process which incurs long rollback. Letting the package execute continues the execution for days!

I've tried using Data flow task for the same but it takes so much more time compared in stored procedure that I'm trying to avoid using it.

Comment: Good first attempt but we'll specific details about your problem. How is your package structured? What does your source and destination tables look like? What is the source for your stored procedures?

Comment: Can you clarify: the stored procedure and database are the same but the executing SSIS Server is different?